# variable not recognized inside contentscript

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

I am trying to create an addon which after a user logs in to my site I will try and read the session id of that domain and use it for further interactions with my addon. I use the [online addon builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/) and  I have this code which I want to read the cookies:

```js
var data = require("self").data;
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var cookieMgr = Cc["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"].getService(Ci.nsICookieManager); 
var cm = require("context-menu");
cm.Item({
  label: "My Menu Item",
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function (node, data) {' +
                 'for (var e = cookieMgr.enumerator; e.hasMoreElements();) {  ' +
                 'var cookie = e.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsICookie);   ' +
                 ' console.log(cookie.host + ";" + cookie.name + "=" + cookie.value + "\\n");'+
                 '}});'
});
```

but it throws an error every time I click on the 'My Menu Item' button, saying `cookieMgr`, the variable is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content script context is entirely disconnected from the addon script context. It's not so easy to grasp this when you're using `contentScript`, but if you put it in another file and use it through a `contentScriptFile` it becomes more obvious. Content scripts are run in the context of the document, while addon scripts aren't.